# кнопка выполняющая функцию

Tags: javascript, браузер, макросы, автоматизация, tampermonkey

Пыталась добавить кнопку, при нажатии на которую запускать скрипт в котором происходит нажатие на элементы на странице.

```
var d1 = document.querySelector('.selector');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<button class="btn_1w" id="clickMe" style="width:50px"><span>Кнопка</span></button>');
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function () { 
document.querySelector(':nth-child(3) > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2) > span').click(); 
 };
```

Кнопка добавляется, но при нажатии ошибка в консоли и действие не происходит

```
Uncaught TypeError: d1 is null
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:2
```

Само действие

```
document.querySelector(':nth-child(3) > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2) > span').click();
```

отправленное в консоль работает как нужно, Подскажите пожалуйста, как кнопку эту сделать работоспособной?
Хочу использовать через Tampermonkey

Comment: `var d1 = document.querySelector('.selector');` не находит тут селектор

Comment: Но он там есть, если я например вызываю какой-то аллерт или сообщение в консоль, то кнопка срабатывает без ошибок например: 
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function () { console.log("test"); }
Работает, а вот если добавляю действие как описала выше, то такая ошибка

Comment: Возможно при выполнении JS кнопка еще не появилась на странице?

Comment: Попробуй свой код обернуть в анонимную самовызывающуюся функцию и никогда не используй `var`, используй `const`. Здесь очень странное сообщение - какое оно имеет отношение к клику, когда он независим от  `d1`. Возможно начались проблемы с исполнением скриптов, обрати внимание что пишет Google по поводу расширений - [последний пункт](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/#migration-summary), цитата: _удалена поддержка ... выполнения произвольных строк_.